# Runtime Error '9' Subscript Out Of Range: VBA Code to Append data from Multiple Workbooks into a single Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 10 workbooks in a testing folder. All of them have a sheet labeled Detail. I need to copy out data from that sheet in the range B21:BT (stop after hitting a blank row-- as there the number of rows can change for each workbook.) I would like to paste all of this data into a workbook that is already created labeled Master.

Here is what I have so far but im hitting a runtime '9' subscript out of range error:

```
Sub CopyRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Const strPath As String = "G:\GLOBALPRGM\STAFF\Testing\"
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir("*.xlsx*")
Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
        .Sheets("Detail").Range("B20:BT" & .Sheets("Detail").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

any help cracking this one is much appreciated.

Comment: I can probably guess but which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Is the "Master" workbook saved in the same folder, and does it also contain a "Detail" sheet? Otherwise `wkbSource` does not have a sheet named "Detail", or `wkbDest` does not have a sheet named "Master", or both.

Comment: Skin- .Sheets("Detail").Range("B20:BT"..... is throwing me the error.

Comment: Ben- Master is not saved in the same folder. It was previously.... and i moved it bc i figured there would be an issue with it trying to loop. Master.xlsx only has one sheet labeled "Master". I might need to be more clear in my variable declaration here. As my destination workbook will be the master one and my Source wkb will be 1 of the 10 in the folder and should loop thru until all the data is appended on one sheet (master). Lmk if additional clarification is needed... been a long week... I might not being clear. Tyty

Comment: Do all the detail sheets have cell filled in B20 or below. Is `.Sheets("Detail").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` always at least 20 ?

Comment: Indeed they do... there is a table starting at B20 going down to B30 then there are two bank rows followed by some extra disclaimer text. I only need what's in the table.--- there will alwasy be some data above B20.... The table header will always start at row 20 and span down some number of rows before ending... the data above row 20 is constant but irrelevant

Comment: Is the "master' workbook the only one open when you run this?  You need to be sure none of the source workbooks is already open, or you may get odd behavior...

Comment: Indeed Yes it is the only work book open and i still get the runtime error 9--- on the postive note after i dismiss the errror the first workbook in the folder opens up. Progress!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some message boxes to help identify the source of the error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRange()
   
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook, wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim strExtension As String, msg As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean, lastrow As Long
    
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wkbDest.Sheets("Master")
    
    Const strPath As String = "G:\GLOBALPRGM\STAFF\Testing\"
    Const WSNAME = "Detail"
    ChDir strPath
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    strExtension = Dir("*.xlsx*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
    
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension, ReadOnly:=True)
        With wkbSource
        
            bFound = False
            For Each wsSrc In .Sheets
                If wsSrc.Name = WSNAME Then
                    bFound = True
                    lastrow = wsSrc.Range("B" & wsSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    If lastrow < 20 Then
                        MsgBox wkbSource.Name & " last row (<20) = " & lastrow, vbExclamation, strPath
                    Else
                        wsSrc.Range("B20:BT" & lastrow).Copy wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        msg = msg & vbLf & lastrow - 19 & " rows : " & wkbSource.Name
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
             Next
             If bFound = False Then MsgBox "No sheet named " & WSNAME & " in " & wkbSource.Name, vbExclamation, strPath
            .Close savechanges:=False
                      
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If msg = "" Then
         MsgBox "Nothing found in " & strPath, vbExclamation
    Else
         MsgBox "Files scanned ;" & msg, vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ty for the help. I am now getting the Runtime Error 9 subscript out of range on the line: Set wsDest =wkbDest.Sheets(Master").... Master.xlsx is the only workbook open when I run the Macro and it only has the one tab labeled Master. There are no clearly erroneous spellings or typos.

Comment: Maybe I do not have the necessary references enabled.

Comment: @user174 Check there are no spaces like `" Master" or "Master "`

Comment: yes can confirm there are no Spaces (at least ones I can see) some of the files are auto generated so maybe the issue is there.

Comment: I am going to create some new dummie files to test this on.. Will update you if it thats the issue

Comment: I created whole new files and made sure the naming conventions were 100% accurate with the macro code and still no luck....

Comment: If the master is .xlsx. Where is this code located ? `Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook` assumes  it is but that would have to be `master.xlsm`.

Comment: the code is actually on my personal.xlsb folder.  I changed Master to Sheet1 in both the workbook and code and now i am getting all of the error handling dialogus popping up,, might be able to handle it from here

Comment: @user174 I guessed that might be the problem from one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249245)

Comment: So now, I am getting to the point where It gives the last dialog box "Files Scanned scans all my files and returns the number of rows" Then the program ends without copying and appending the data into the consolidated sheet.

Comment: @user174 Did you change `Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook` to `Set wkbDest = ActiveWorkbook` ?

Comment: HA! that was the fix. You are a life saver!!! ty so very much!